# Fragment enter animation, animate just some views

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-transitions

Let's say I have two fragments A and B I can set custom animations like a slide in or fade in when fragment B is transitioning from fragment A using setCustomAnimation() this method I think animates fragments viewGroup (parent), but how could I animate different views separately in parents viewGroup when switching to fragment B? for example I would want to fade in content of fragment B, but slide in toolbar.

Comment: Your question is way too broad and it's hard to have a correct answer, but I can give you a starting point. If you have shared elements between the two fragments you can use something like shared element transitions (read more about here: https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50). If you want to animate only a view from one fragment, you can use `OnResume` from fragments to start the animation then.

Comment: I mean when you setCustomAnimation() before the transition to the second fragment it applies that animation to parent viewGroup, but I want to apply animations to separate views inside that viewGroup when the transition happens. I'm aware of transitions, but all of them happens after viewGroup is created.